# How to loop and display (n) feeds using simpleXML and position()

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml, simpledom

I am using simpleXML and I want to loop though the feed to only display 5 shows using the position() method, but have no joy in getting it to work

```
foreach($xml->sortedXPath('TV[position() < 5 and ProgrammeName="MTV"]', 'TransmissionDate', SORT_DESC) as $i => $item)
{

    print "<a href='?v=".$item->ID."&a=false' class='link'>\n";
    print "\t<span class=\"text\">" .trunc($item->ShortSynopsis,25, " "). "</span>\n";
    print "\t</a>";
}
```

any suggestions on how I can get this working

this is the XML data I am working with

http://deniselashlley.co.uk/test/data.xml

Comment: You can get things to work even if it is no joy - so, where's the problem? SCNR ;-) Seriously: Without a chance to see your input XML, all bets why this approach does not work are off. Please edit your question to include the XML document.

Comment: its a large piece of xml but this file gives you the general idea :)

Comment: have you tried `foreach($xml->sortedXPath('/ArrayOfCatchUp/TV[…]', …)`?

Comment: that didn't work got an error - Argument 1 passed to SimpleDOM::sort() must be an array, boolean

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a repost, but anyway...

NiseNise wants to sort nodes then keep the top 5. The problem is that this XPath expression selects the first 5 nodes in the document, then the method sorts them. What you need to do is sort *all* the nodes then only process the first 5.

```
foreach($xml->sortedXPath('TV[ProgrammeName="MTV"]', 'TransmissionDate', SORT_DESC) as $i => $item)
{
    if ($i > 5)
    {
        break;
    }

    print "<a href='?v=".$item->ID."&a=false' class='link'>\n";
    // etc...
}
```

I forgot to mention, `sortedXPath()` isn't part of SimpleXML, it's part of a [library extending SimpleXML](http://code.google.com/p/simpledom/), hence the retagging.

Comment: Yeah I had that before but then certain times during the week it would display 6 shows (as a new show is added), so I was hoping the position() method would work better.

Comment: That would be *extremely* weird. I can't think of a situation where this loop would output more than 5 entries. If anything, initialize `$i` yourself and increment it yourself inside of the loop. It will be *impossible* then to output more than 5, unless of course you have another routine that resets the value of `$i`. Most likely, your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: I do have this additional filter that does not to display future shows before they are actually transmitted
$today_date = date('D j M, g:ia');
if(strtotime($item->TransmissionDate) < time(strtotime($today_date))){ 
print "<a href='?v=".$item->ID."&a=false' class='link'>\n";
}

maybe this might affect it????

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that your loop will begin at `item[0]`? So `$i > 5` will output the first 6 nodes because the count would begin at item 0. Simply change it to `$i > 4` and that should fix your problem.